# Impact of non-normality of residuals on hypothesis tests in OLS

Tags: least-squares

I am doing an OLS regression in R and my residuals are not normally distributed. Does this mean that hypothesis tests are not reliable anymore, e.g. if I look at the F-Statistic of the summary in R? Can I do anything to account for this problem of non-normal distributed residuals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assumption of error's normality is only needed for statistical inference if your sample is small (say n<100 to say something).

For large samples, one relies on the CLT.

In other words. You do nothing. unless your dependent variable is of limited distribution (discrete for example), OLS is fine.